# how to set error_reporting(0) in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, reporting, codeigniter-2

I am using codeigniter and I want to set php `error_reporting(0)` so that when table don't have value then php won't show me error like this one

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: models/staff_model.php

Line Number: 42
```

If I add an if condition where i check if result from model has value great then 0 like this one

```
<?php 
  if($result > 0) {
  foreach($results as $orderlisting) {
      $orderid = $orderlisting->Order_Id;
       ?>
```

Then I will not show me error, now I want to disable this kind of error in CodeIgniter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeIgniter root `index.php` set **ENVIRONMENT** with`production`

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
```

And your issue about $results.

`$results` variable is not object. If it is truely array, use like `$orderlisting['Order_Id']`

And changed `if($result > 0) {` with `if(count($results) > 0) {`

Doesnt exist `$result` variable

```
<?php 
if(count($results) > 0) {
  foreach($results as $orderlisting) {
      $orderid = $orderlisting['Order_Id'];
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to disable the error messages because you don't want your application to work properly?

That's a bit strange imho.

You should always check for proper results, especially if the rest of your application depends on this data.

Comment: This should be a comment, saying that, I do totally agree with it